# jQuery ColorBox - It causes a post back of my current page. How to prevent it?

Tags: jquery, postback, colorbox

Given below is my piece of code. Even with "return false" provided on all the right places the jQuery colorbox causes my page to post to the server which I want to avoid.
The colorbox renders properly though but I do not want the whole page to post back for the same. Thanks in advance.

```
FI.quickView = {

    init: function (obj) {

        $(obj).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(obj).colorbox({
            href: "somefile.html",
            width: 890,
            height: 680,
            onLoad: function () { return false; },
            onOpen: function () { return false; }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need in this code, because it doesn't have any sense:

```
onLoad: function () { return false; }, 
onOpen: function () { return false; }
```

It's hard to understand what is `obj`, but if you want prevent form submit, then use this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
});
```

Where `form` is selector of your form and this code you can add to `onLoad` event.

Comment: When would it be ideal to prevent form submit? On authentication handling events?

Comment: @BenSewards You need to prevent form submit when you click `<input type="submit" />` (in `<form>` block) and you want post data with `ajax`.

Comment: What if you use the input button to trigger an ajax call, won't post back be ignored in this case? I'm relatively new to ajax requests, so sorry for the easy question!

Comment: @BenSewards Default submit button behavior is submit form, you can also use `preventDefault` for submit button, but on `Enter` form will submit with page reload.